# Sharing files with my friend

Tags: ipad

I want to share files with my friend.

I used Sprend.com to share it. But my friend could not open it.

My friend is using an Ipad mini MD528KN/A.

She has no access to a computer.

I am using a PC.

How to solve the problem.

Regards Gustaf

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the file, a LOT.

The iPad has no (visible) filesystem. So unlike a Mac or PC you can't move things around as you wish. You have to have an application that will deal with it in the form you send it via the method you send it by.

Yes you can send an .mp3 but there is no way to then add it to the music.app without a Mac or PC and iTunes. The same goes for MS Office files, Photoshop files and many other proprietary file formats.

Perhaps if you edited your question to say specifically what kind of file and what she needs to do with it, we could be of more assistance.

---

Like @stuffe said a free Dropbox account could help you with this. Dropbox will let you play videos right in their file browser as long as they are generally playable on your Mac (EG H.264, MP4, MOV files, etc.) Dropbox is free for up to 2GB of storage.

Comment: Hi. Its a movie i want to share. Its in mp4 format. Does it work better with other formats?

Answer (score 1):

As @SteveChambers says it depends what the file is as to whether they will be able to open it.  If it's simple small files such as documents, then maybe email will be sufficient.  Larger documents can be shared by something such as [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) which will provide a filesystem like structure to share files, but even then if the files particularly large or from a less simple application say from a CAD package etc, then they may also require a native iPad App to be able to load the file into after receiving it.